# What is the nature of the interlude at the beginning of the Season 2 finale of "Siren"?

Tags: siren

At the beginning of the final episode of the second season, Ben is about to rescue Ian, the reporter, from his car.

> After Ben does so, Ian goes public and a strange dystopian future ensues in which the people with merfolk ancestry are taken in by the government for experimentation, Canada offers them asylum, Xander helps capture Donna's daughter, and finally Maddie, Ryn, and Ben make a run for the border only to be caught be the military with lethal consequences. Then it is revealed that this is not what actually happened: rather, Ben let Ian die.

After watching this twice, it still seems confusing. Are we dealing with:

- some sort of supernatural vision, despite there being no indication that Ben, or anyone, had this sort of power;
- an incredibly long, detailed and completely speculative scenario playing out in his imagination, in the space of about a second, about what would happen if he saved Ian;
- or even the actual consequences that would ensue if he did so, most of which he would have essentially no way of even guessing?

Or something else altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second one, it's all Ben's imagination. From an interview with show producers Eric Wald and Emily Whitesell for *Paste Magazine*:

> ***Paste*: Once we figured out what the twist was, that did throw the whole legitimacy of the future we saw into question. Like—that’s just *Ben*’s idea of the future, right? How did you end on his being the lens through which you’d explore that possible future?**
>
> **Whitesell**: When you go back to the pilot, he is so central. He is who the story, in many ways, is about. And of course the story has turned out to be very much about Ryn and where she comes from and her own people, but it started out from [Ben’s] point of view. So to get to go back and land in that place, to give him his point of view back about this whole thing and where he’s evolved to as a character from the beginning, we thought was important.
>
> **Wald**: And I do have a feeling that some fans will go back and watch the episode again, once they’ve seen the twist. And [when they do], they’ll see that even the stories that Ben is not a part of, they’re still told *through* Ben’s perspective, and it’s still Ben’s anxieties and what he’s imagining could happen. Like, we bring back that lure that Xander (Ian Verdun) found way back in 1.02—Ben’s worried, *oh, god, is Xander going to use that lure to capture more mermaids?* Same thing with his father—all the conflict he’s had with his dad sort of comes out in what he imagines his role would be in that [version of] the story. [...] **And when he’s down in the water there, holding his breath outside the car door, that’s a real moment of crisis, too. So all of his anxieties are amplified in that moment.**
>
> <sub>["Siren EPs Dissect that Big Finale Twist and Tease Season Three", Alexis Gunderson for *Paste Magazine*, August 1, 2019](https://www.pastemagazine.com/tv/siren/siren-season-2-finale-explained/)</sub>

The producers not wanting to go that far into "world-class events", it's also a way for them to explore a possibility of what could have happened, once again, through Ben:

> ***Paste*: *Siren* has always taken big swings, but this episode was an even bigger departure still from the kind of storytelling fans have gotten used to over the past two seasons. What was the impetus behind making this finale this story?**
>
> **Eric Wald**: All along we’ve been interested in having to keep a lid on this secret, and the danger of the secret getting out, and what that would mean both to our characters and to the world at large. So I think for us it was really exciting in the finale to actually lean into that and to ask, okay, what would happen if the secret of the mermaids *did* get out?
>
> **Emily Whitesell**: The whole contrivance of the twist is, we don’t actually want to live in a series that has to go *that* big and *that* far. It was a way for us to go to that place in our minds without having to commit to some sort of giant, end-of-the-world production for the rest of the series.

Note that in S03E01, when Ben talks to Maddie about his decision, he doesn't mention some kind of vision either:

> BEN: In the water, I had a chance to save him, I could have gotten him out, but I didn't. He kidnapped Ryn, Maddie. He was gonna kill us on the road. I know what would have happened if he shared the secret with the world. One life. To save an entire species.

For what it's worth, there *is* some kind of way to "see the future", also revealed in season 3, namely to

> have a deceased siren's spirit visit and warn you, as Sarge did when telling Helen that "war was coming".

But that's not what happened here.